# pydantic: How to parse & validate a model from a string with the model attributes as names (not as python dict)

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic, sqlmodel

I'm able to export records as a csv from my fastapi/sqlmodel/sqladmin backend. The sqladmin (backend panel) only allows limited configuration of the export format and I end up with the following export data for my many-to-many relationship called **"assessed_in"**:

```
"[Period(id=1, name='1. quarter 2022', period_id='q1_2022', status=<PeriodStatusEnum.in_assessment: 'in_assessment'>), Period(id=2, name='2. Quarter 2022', period_id='q2_2022', status=<PeriodStatusEnum.in_assessment: 'in_assessment'>)]"
```

My models are setup as follows:

```
# Database Models

class PeriodStatusEnum(str, enum.Enum):
    in_assessment = "in_assessment"
    readonly = "readonly"
    hidden = "hidden"

class Period(BaseClass, table=True):
    period_id: str = Field(index=True, unique=True)
    name: str
    status: PeriodStatusEnum = Field(sa_column=Column(Enum(PeriodStatusEnum)))

class DimensionPeriodLink(SQLModel, table=True):
    dimension_id: int | None = Field(default=None, foreign_key="dimension.id", primary_key=True)
    period_id: int | None = Field(default=None, foreign_key="period.id", primary_key=True)
    
class Dimension(BaseClass, table=True):
    dimension_id: str = Field(index=True, unique=True)
    name_EN: str
    name_DE: str
    order_nr: int
    assessed_in: list[Period] = Relationship(link_model=DimensionPeriodLink)
```

In a later stage I need to read in the csv and create the records with the many to many relationship in python -> which works fine for all attributes except the "assessed_in" m2m relationship (as it's not a pure dict).

```
#when I read in the exported csv file, I get the following data per row/record
dimension_dict = {'assessed_in': "[Period(status=<PeriodStatusEnum.in_assessment: 'in_assessment'>, id=1, name='1. Quartal 2022', period_id='q1_2022'), Period(status=<PeriodStatusEnum.in_assessment: 'in_assessment'>, id=2, name='2. Quartal 2022', period_id='q2_2022')]", 'level_definitions': '[]', 'questions': '[]', 'id': '1', 'dimension_id': 'DIM10', 'name_EN': 'Organizational structure and roles', 'name_DE': 'Organisationsstruktur und Rollen', 'order_nr': '1'}
new_record = Dimension.model_validate(dimension_dict)
```

What would be a smart solution to parse that model including the relationship with pydantic/sqlmodel?
Thanks a lot for your inputs, it's highly appreciated! <3

Comment: what is `dimension_dict`?
Can you create minimal code, that reproduces your problem (input data, models, expected output, real output)?

Comment: Can you provide a more complete example of your export data?

Comment: I've added an example of the exported data